# How to keep groups with at least one value less than 24 using pandas groupby.filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
CCode   CId      State       Age
326112  1217012  Nebraska    20
326112  1217012  Nebraska    75
326112  1217012  Nebraska    107

320113  1317012  Alabama     37
320113  1317012  Alabama     38
320113  1317012  Alabama     39

320180  8017061  Arkansas    37
320180  8017061  Arkansas    38
320180  8017061  Arkansas    39

326112  1217011  California  36
326112  1217011  California  37
326112  1217011  California  38
```

I am trying to keep groups that have at least one age below 24, and re-group the filtered groups.

I tried grouping by 4 columns and filtering with a chained lambda:

```
df.groupby(['State', 'CId', 'CCode', 'Age']).filter(lambda x:x['Age'].sum()<23).groupby(['State', 'CId', 'CCode', 'Age']).std()
```

This loses the rest of the group:

```
CCode   CId      State       Age
326112  1217012  Nebraska    20
```

Needed output:

```
CCode   CId      State       Age
326112  1217012  Nebraska    20
326112  1217012  Nebraska    75
326112  1217012  Nebraska    107
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. I think you want to remove `Age` from the list of columns to group. I also don't understand why you're using `sum()`. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It's because of `lambda x:x['Age'].sum()<23`. In your first groupby, the data is grouped one row per group; so `sum` is equal to the individual `Age`. Then you filtered less than 23, so only the very first row of your sample data survives your filter.

Comment: Maybe you could show a sample dataframe containing the output that you want?

Comment: Chris, thank you for clarifying. is it possible to use a range() in the filter? I have tried a few things so far like so: 

```df.groupby([‘State’, ‘CId’, ‘CCode’, ‘Age’]).filter(lambda x:x[‘Age’].sum()<23 and x[‘Age’].sum()>75).groupby([‘State’, ‘CId’, ‘CCode’, ‘Age’]).std()```

and also looking into other solutions: 

```df.where(df.Age.all()<23 and df.Age.all()>75).groupby([‘State’, ‘CId’, ‘CCode’, ‘Age’])``` though, neither work.

Comment: I don't get your logic. What is it you want to do? _remove groups that start below the age of 24_: Does this mean that to remove groups whose first age is less than 24? If so, why do you only have `Nebraska` in your needed output? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: Ahh, okay. I understand, good job pointing that out. It should be the other way around if that's what I wanted. So, what I would like to do is keep the groups that have an age starting below 24. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [clarification from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70239629/why-does-a-pandas-group-by-filter-show-me-one-table-row-instead-of-returning-the#comment124164638_70239629):

> what I would like to do is keep the groups that have an age starting below 24

1. Remove `Age` from the grouper
2. Test if [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) `Age` in the group is [`lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) (less than) 24

```
df.groupby(['State', 'CId', 'CCode']).filter(lambda g: g.Age.lt(24).any())

#     CCode      CId     State  Age
# 0  326112  1217012  Nebraska   20
# 1  326112  1217012  Nebraska   75
# 2  326112  1217012  Nebraska  107
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to strictly filter based on the *starting age* only, one way would be to use `iloc`:

```
df.groupby(["State", "CId", "CCode"]).filter(lambda x: x["Age"].iloc[0] < 24)
```

Output:

```
    CCode      CId     State  Age
0  326112  1217012  Nebraska   20
1  326112  1217012  Nebraska   75
2  326112  1217012  Nebraska  107
```