# How to filter groups in dataset by value in column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, filter, group-by

I have a dataset:

```
id      val
1       "a"  
1       "b" 
1       "c"   
2       "b" 
2       "c"
2       "d"  
3       "a"
4       "h"  
4       "i"
```

I want to remove groups based on "id", is there is no "a" in column val in that group. so desired output is:

```
id      val
1       "a"  
1       "b" 
1       "c"   
3       "a"
```

How could I do that?

Comment: Are you trying to keep all IDs that have at least one "a" ?

Comment: @Aymen yes i do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep groups with at least one value less than 24 using pandas groupby.filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70239629/how-to-keep-groups-with-at-least-one-value-less-than-24-using-pandas-groupby-fil)

Comment: As per the suggested duplicate, you can try: `df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: x.val.str.contains('a').any())`. Or you can also do something like: `df.loc[df.id.isin(df.loc[df.val.str.contains('a'), 'id'].tolist())]`.

Comment: @ouroboros1 yeah sorry it is a right answer