# Drop rows with specific conditions

Tags: python, pandas, drop

My DataFrame looks like this:

[image: df]

What I would like to do is: if weight is once less than 70, drop all rows that have the same name. So, if Thomas' weight was once less than 70, drop all his data and repeat this for all the other names.
So in my case the result would be:

[image: result]

Code to rebuild data:

```
data = {'date': {0: Timestamp('2014-01-01 00:00:00'), 
                 1: Timestamp('2014-01-02 00:00:00'), 
                 2: Timestamp('2014-01-03 00:00:00'), 
                 3: Timestamp('2014-01-04 00:00:00'), 
                 4: Timestamp('2014-01-05 00:00:00'), 
                 5: Timestamp('2014-01-06 00:00:00'), 
                 6: Timestamp('2014-01-07 00:00:00'), 
                 7: Timestamp('2014-01-08 00:00:00')}, 
        'name': {0: 'Thomas', 1: 'Thomas', 2: 'Thomas', 3: 'Max', 
                 4: 'Max', 5: 'Paul', 6: 'Paul', 7: 'Paul'}, 
        'size': {0: 130, 1: 132, 2: 132, 3: 143, 4: 150, 5: 140, 
                 6: 140, 7: 141}, 
        'weight': {0: 60, 1: 65, 2: 80, 3: 75, 4: 56, 5: 75, 6: 76, 7: 74}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Just add the condition. If weight < 70, look for its name (Thomas). And then simply delete all rows with Thomas in it. How does your code look like right now?

Answer (score 1):

Try as follows:

- Select column `name` from the `df` based on [`Series.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) and turn into a list with [`Series.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html). Feed the resulting list to [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and combine with unary operator (`~`) for selection from the `df`.

```
res = df[~df.name.isin(df[df.weight.lt(70)].name.tolist())]

print(res)

        date  name  size  weight
5 2014-01-06  Paul   140      75
6 2014-01-07  Paul   140      76
7 2014-01-08  Paul   141      74
```

Or as a variant on this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70239800/18470692) to a similar question, try as follows:

- Use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on column `name` and apply [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) with a lambda function, keeping the group only if [`Series.ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) is `True` for [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html) its values.

```
res = df.groupby('name').filter(lambda x: x.weight.ge(70).all())

# same result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
names = list(df[df['weight']<70]['name'])
df_new = df[~(df['name'].isin(names))]
```